# Is $\{\lim X_n\ge 0\}$ a tail event if $X_n$ converges almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge0}$ be a random sequences such that $X_n\to X_{\infty}$ almost surely. Let $\mathcal{T}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},...)$ be the tail $\sigma$-algebra.
Is $A=\{X_{\infty}\ge 0\}$ a tail event (i.e. $A\in \mathcal{T}$)?. Similar question for $B=\{X_{\infty}>0\}$.

There is a related counterexample when $X_n$ is a sum of random variables $\xi_n$ (however the tail sigma algebra of $(X_n)$ is different from the one of $(\xi_n)$), see the following question
[showing that $\{ \limsup_{n \to \infty} S_n > 0 \}$ is not a tail $\sigma$ algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3863573/showing-that-limsup-n-to-infty-s-n-0-is-not-a-tail-sigma-algeb?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show limsup/liminf is in tail field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280749/show-limsup-liminf-is-in-tail-field)

Comment: @SangchulLee There is a difference between $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$ and $X_n$.

Comment: @user10354138 Ah yes, I just realized that. Thank you! I guess I need some sleep to restore my cognitive ability...

Comment: Almost sure convegence is not enough. You require convergence at every point.

Comment: So if I can prove $B$ is not a tail event then $A$ is not too. However, I could not find a counter-example for $B$ assuming that $X_n$ converges almost surely/or surely converges. I am a bit confused now :(

Comment: Complete the tail $\sigma$-algebra with respect to your $\mathbb{P}$, otherwise you could make $X_\infty$ differs from $\lim X_n$ on a null subset $N\subset\{\omega:X_n(\omega)\text{ converges}\}$ to kill any meaningful statement (e.g., $X_n=1$ but $X_\infty=-1$ on a null set).  Then remember the limit of a sequence is positive iff the sequence is eventually positive.

Comment: @user10354138
Thanks. I think that we have $\{\lim_n X_{n}\ge 0\}=\bigcap_{n\ge1}\bigcup_{k\ge n} \{X_n\ge 0\}$. Is that what you mean? The case of limsup and $X_n$ does not converges, the identity is certainly not true.

Comment: Oops, I mean bounded away from $0$ not just positive.  $\{\liminf_n X_n>0\}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}, q>0}\{\liminf_n X_n\geq q\}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}, q>0}\bigcup_n\bigcap_{m>n}\{X_m\geq q/2\}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}, q>0}\bigcup_n\bigcap_{m>n}\{X_m\geq q\}$  Similarly $\limsup$, and the nonstrict inequality is just complement up to a null set.

Comment: No, we could identify $\limsup X_n>0$, it is $\bigcup_{q>0}\bigcap_n\bigcup_{m>n}\{X_m>q\}$.  Similarly, we could identify where $X_n$ converge/does not converge, by writing the Cauchy sequences definition with $1/n$s instead of arbitrary $\epsilon$s.  So if you define $X_\infty$ the conventional way: $\lim X_n$ if it exists, $0$ otherwise, then $X_\infty$ is measurable with you unaugmented tail $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @user10354138. I am a bit confused since there is a counter-example that $\{\limsup X_n>0\}$ is not tail event when $X_n$ does not converge.

Comment: @user2096016 You are confusing $\limsup S_n>0$ with $\limsup X_n>0$.  The counterexample in your link uses the freedom to choose initial $X_1$ in $S_n=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$.

Comment: i see, they are different tail sigma-algebras. The tail sigma-algebra generated by $(S_n)$ is different from the tail sigma-algebra generated by its increment.